# Selenium and java servlet and javaScript

Tags: javascript, selenium, servlets, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I have a situation in which I want Selenium webdriver to run on client.

I have a webpage with Submit button inside form.

In form's action attribute I am calling servlet `action="servletName"`.

Now in servlet I have following

```
@WebServlet("/servletName")
public class chckserv extends HttpServlet {
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException 
{
 System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","path//geckodriver.exe");
 System.out.println("In Servlet");
 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
 driver.get("https://www.google.com");
 response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
 response.getOutputStream().write("Done".getBytes("UTF-8"));
 response.getOutputStream().flush();
 response.getOutputStream().close(); 
 }
}
```

When I click on button on HTML page WebDriver instance is getting started on server.

Now here is waht I want to do. The webdriver instance should be running at client side.

**Is it possible in any way keeping in mind current scenario??**

Answer (score 0):

> The webdriver instance should be running at client side.

Am guessing that you are referring to a remote machine which is not the same one as the machine on which your servlet is running.

If that's a correct guess, then yes you can very well do this. You would need to make use of the Selenium Grid for doing this.

You would make use of

`RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://remoteHostIP:remoteHostPort/wd/hub"), DesiredCapabilities.firefox());`

to instantiate your webdriver instance.

Take a look at the below documentation to learn how to work with the Selenium Grid.

- Selenium HQ documentation : http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp
- My Blog post : https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2012/01/23/setting-up-grid2-and-working-with-it/

Comment: In grid my hub would be server (having servlet) and node would be client machine right...?

Then If i start webdriver from client that would launch webdriver on hub not on node(client).


**I am not allowed to run grid on client machine (can not make client as hub)**